# Is it possible to run a macro externally on an excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I export data daily from software to excel files.

There's a lot of repetitive tasks so I created a macro.

1. I open the new exported excel file and then save it as "Macro-Enabled worksheet"
2. I open the Macro-enabled worksheet
3. I import the macros into the excel file
4. I run the macros

Is there a way to run the macro without doing all the steps above using VBS or any other way?

I don't know if there's a solution out there, but I would prefer if an external VBA operator would ask for the location of the exported file and then does the rest

Comment: Use your macros to request a file name and then run using a `Workbook` object, then instead of say `sheets(1).range("a1:A10")` you say `wbMyWorkbookOpened.sheets(1).range("a1:A10")`   So a control workbook that just opens the workbook and runs said macros

Comment: Do you import the macros only to run them from the newly created workbook? Will they be frequently used in the future, too? You can run a maro from another workbook, or from another application (VBScript, for instance) but it maybe is not be necessary, if you have the necessary macros in a different workbook, or in an add-in. They must be adapted, probably, to not refer only the workbook where they belong to. Can you better explain **what you really want accomplishing**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily open any other workbook and run any commands on that workbook. So you can have the following macro in an Excel file `MyMacroFile.xlsm` and manipulate data in `C:\Temp\WorkbookToRunMacroOn.xlsx` for example.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoTasksOnOtherWorkbook()
    'open another workbook
    Dim OpenWorkbook As Workbook
    Set OpenWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Temp\WorkbookToRunMacroOn.xlsx")
    
    OpenWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Changed A1 in another workbook"
    
    'don't forget to close the workbook and save or not
    OpenWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

If you want to ask the user to select a file to open you can use the [Application.FileDialog property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog) it returns a file name that you can then use in the `Application.Workbooks.Open` to open it.